# Unable to run `npm install` in fresh Phoenix project on Powershell windows

Tags: npm, webpack, elixir, npm-install, phoenix-framework

### Background

I am trying to do a [Phoenix LiveView](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view) project to learn how it works. To this extent, I have, in my windows 10 machine, installed Elixir and NPM via [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). I have also successfully run the commands:

```
$ mix archive.install hex phx_new
$ mix phx.new demo --live
```

### Problem

The problem comes after running the second command. After its completion I am told to follow some additional steps:

```
We are almost there! The following steps are missing:

    $ cd test_app
    $ cd assets && npm install && node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --mode development
```

In specific, the `npm install` part fails:

```
> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.18.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"4.41.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!     dev babel-loader@"^8.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   3 more (copy-webpack-plugin, css-loader, hard-source-webpack-plugin)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev mini-css-extract-plugin@"^0.9.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.4.0" from mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-29T08_41_13_010Z-debug.log
```

This is a fresh project. I am confused as to why this is even happening.
If I run `npm install --force` then I am greeted with a wall of errors, I assume because of this issue.

### Question

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the contents of your `package.json`? It seems like there are different webpack versions required by some dependencies which is causing conflicts. Also, is `webpack -v` a valid command for you on a terminal? What does it show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

The issue here was the node-sass version. There is currently a bug with Node 15 and that package.

https://elixirforum.com/t/unable-to-run-npm-install-in-fresh-phoenix-project-on-powershell-windows/37164/4?u=fl4m3ph03n1x

The issue can be fixed by using the command:

`npm i --legacy-peer-deps`